# Access DV Cam over Firewire via Adobe Flex/Air

Tags: apache-flex, air, camera, firewire

I am trying to move an internal app from a Windows Media Encoder-based solution to an Adobe Flex/Air solution that involves streaming video/audio.  I can use the Camera and Microphone classes in Flex to access webcams, etc. but our DV cameras (connected via Firewire) don't show up in those collections.

Does anyone have any insight on how to get around this?  Target platform is primarily Windows 7 (although bonus points for a solution that would also work on Mac OS X).

I'm willing to consider almost anything that will expose the audio and video streams from the DV camera to the Flex app, preferably via the Camera and Microphone classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another question from series "How I do in AIR (something AIR can't do)" :) There is one answer to all series - use native helper. If you already have one, you only need to connect it to Flash environment. To expose streams via Camera and Microphone classes, I guess, you need to emulate these devices in the system. Maybe it's easier to connect streams to server which will deliver them via network. If you go server route, you need to transform video/audio to FLV format - this way you can feed them to Flash/Flex applications.

Comment: Ugh - not exactly the answer I was looking for, but probably the only one that's correct.  I guess I'll have to look into virtual device driver programming for Windows and Mac OS X - yuck.